# Storage drives frequently spinning up even when they're not needed. Can I stop this?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I'm on Windows 7 x64 and I have a striped volume which consists of four hard drives.

I use the volume exclusively for storage of large files like movies/TV shows and don't need to access it very frequently (my system drive is a single SSD). My power options are set to turn off drives after 3 minutes of inactivity.

The problem is that Windows - in its infinite wisdom - frequently spins up all four disks whenever I do certain things even if they don't directly involve data on the storage volume.

For example, the drives spin up when I:

• Adjust the audio volume using Windows' volume slider (SndVol32.exe)
• Click "Save File As" in Chrome or Firefox (even if the previously used directory was not on the storage volume)
• Click "Shut Down" - even if the drives are off, they spin up again before the computer powers off.

Is there some workaround for this? Is there some way - any way, including buying external enclosures etc. - that I can make Windows think that the drives basically don't exist until I actually manually click on their Windows Explorer icon?

It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Have you disabled indexing of those drives? The indexing routine will periodically check all drives for changes. And they will always spin up on a shutdown, no stopping that.

Comment: Yes I have. I guess I may have to consider a NAS solution or something.

Comment: That would work most of the time... Although if they are mapped to a drive letter it might not help the Save issue, Windows will always check the drives to show them in Explorer, but it doesn't check inactive network shares. I really don't understand the volume thing though, can't explain that one at all.

Comment: I used ProcessMonitor to investigate the volume thing. SndVol32.exe tries to access an old TV episode I watched a week or so ago using MediaPlayer Classic (even though MPC isn't running). It must be somehow tied into MPC or that particular episode. Very strange.